# ??? Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to detect the hole of sequence images in matlab.

But, because the size of my images are soo big (5184*3456) so there is an error

"**??? Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.**"

Here is my Program :

```
   imgname = [imPath filesep filearray(1).name]; % get image name
   I = imread(imgname);
   VIDEO_WIDTH = size(I,2);
   VIDEO_HEIGHT = size(I,1);

   ImSeq = zeros(VIDEO_HEIGHT, VIDEO_WIDTH, NumImages); %**HERE IS THE ERROR LINE**
   for i=1:NumImages
   imgname = [imPath filesep filearray(i).name]; % get image name
   ImSeq(:,:,i) = imread(imgname); % load image
   end
   disp(' ... OK!');
```

Any one have a solution??

Comment: NumImages is the mount of the images. because i want to run the sequence images (like a video from many frame image). But the error line is " ImSeq = zeros(VIDEO_HEIGHT, VIDEO_WIDTH, NumImages);"

Comment: What is the value of NumImages? Is there any chance that such a large array fits into the memory?